Resolve depends on with template YAML Azure Pipelines
Have the following structure:
Main yaml
stages:            
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.Action, 'Action1') }}:
      - stage: PreStep
        jobs:
          - job:
            steps:
              - task: PowerShell@2
                inputs:
                  targetType: "inline"
                  script: |
                    Write-Host "Hello World"
            
  - ${{ if eq(variables['doSomething'], 'true') }}:
      - template: Templates.yaml@templates          
        ${{ eq(parameters.Action, 'Action1') }}:
          dependsOn: "PreStep" # Resolve in template

Templates.yaml
stages:
  - stage: BuildProject
    jobs:
      - job: Build
        steps:
          - task: PowerShell@2
            inputs:
              targetType: "inline"
              script: |
                Write-Host "Hello World"

Can I add the dependsOn in the Main.yaml so when there is a condition it runs before the template??
When running Main.yaml and parameters.Action == "Action", I want to dependOn a stage using the template?


Can I add the dependsOn in the Main.yaml so when there is a condition it runs before the template?

dependsOn is not supported under template expression in Main.yaml.
You can consider to add the dependsOn in the template, sample:
#main.yaml
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: Ubuntu-latest

parameters:
  - name: Action
    default: Action1

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: test1

variables:
  - name: doSomething
    value: true


stages:            
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.Action, 'Action1') }}:
      - stage: PreStep
        jobs:
          - job:
            steps:
              - task: PowerShell@2
                inputs:
                  targetType: "inline"
                  script: |
                    Write-Host "Hello World"
            
  - ${{ if eq(variables['doSomething'], 'true') }}:
      - template: Templates.yaml@templates          
        parameters:
          ActionValue: ${{ parameters.Action }} 

#Templates.yaml
parameters:
- name: 'ActionValue'
  default: 'test'
  type: string

stages:
- ${{ if eq(parameters.ActionValue, 'Action1') }}:
  - stage: BuildProject
    dependsOn: PreStep
    jobs:
      - job: Build
        steps:
          - task: PowerShell@2
            inputs:
              targetType: "inline"
              script: |
                Write-Host "Hello World"
- ${{ else }} :
  - stage: stage2
    jobs:
      - job: job
        steps:
          - script: echo test


Ah okay sucks you can't do that. Thanks for the suggestion

Take a look at my examples @jjnrmason , there is no native support but you can build it, I think my 2nd example is the one you are most likely looking for

It is not by default supported, but what you can do is fix your own way for it, i.e:
Example
# Main yaml
stages:            
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.Action, 'Action1') }}:
      - stage: PreStep
        jobs:
          - job:
            steps:
              - task: PowerShell@2
                inputs:
                  targetType: "inline"
                  script: |
                    Write-Host "Hello World"

  - ${{ if eq(variables['doSomething'], 'true') }}:
      - template: Templates.yaml@templates
        parameters:
         action: ${{ parameters.Action }}

# Templates.yaml
parameters:

 action: ''

stages:

  - stage: BuildProject
    ${{ eq(parameters.action, 'Action1') }}:
      dependsOn: [PreStep]
    ${{ else }}: 
      dependsOn: []
    jobs:
      - job: Build
        steps:
          - task: PowerShell@2
            inputs:
              targetType: "inline"
              script: |
                Write-Host "Hello World"

This example should be able to solve your scenario. I hope this helps and good luck!

Ah this does look promising thanks
